# add row to the DB:: result in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table `BirthDeath` like below:

```
id birthmonth deathmonth
1  1            3
2  4            4
3  2            5
```

The query is for getting either birth or death month,

```
$events = DB::table('BirthDeath')->where('birthmonth',4)->orWhere('deathmonth',4)->paginate(10);
```

This query results in 1 row, however, I need this row to be duplicated (because the birth and death month are the same) and in the view, I am intending to show them separately. My current solution is to duplicate the results if the birth and death month are the same but it does not work. Here is the code

```
events2 = $events;
    foreach ($events as $event) {
            if ($event->birthmonth == $CurrentMonth || $event->deathmonth == $CurrentMonth) {
                $events2->appends($event); <-------- this is the cause of the error
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you looking for the `add` method? also the assignment `$events2 = $events;` is not creating a new collection, both those variables are referencing the same collection

Comment: yes, how can I add?

Comment: with the `add` method or `push`, but it is going to be appended to the end of the items

Comment: that is exactly what i need. can you add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add items to a Collection you can use the `add` or `push` method. `add` takes a single item and `push` **can** take many (variable amount of arguments):

```
$events->add($event);
// or
$events->push($event);
```